# How to specify belongs to dependency in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am writing spec for update function of a controller. I am using two models A and B where models of A and B are as follows:

```
Class A  
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :prop1
   property :prop2
end
```

And model of class B is as follows:

```
 Class B
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :prop1
   property :prop2
   belongs_to :aa, 'A', :required => true
end
```

In factory.rb I could have written the `belongs_to` dependency as follows:

```
factory :b do
   prop1 <val1>
   prop2 <val2>
   association :a
end
```

But I could not write it that way here because here in belongs_to dependency different name of `a` which is here `aa` is given. Can anyone please help me how to write this association in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a `factory :a` then you could do

```
factory :a do
end

factory :b do
  # ...
  association :aa, factory: :a
end
```

BTW why do you bother changing the default relation name? Is this a simplified version of your code to illustrate your needs?